# formula to add new 100 rows from index 101 to 200

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

In google sheet, i want to add new 100 rows from 101 to 200 in column B (Index)

Example:

```
No | Index| Content
1 |101|
2|102|
..
100|200|
```

How can i do it?

Thank you

Comment: Use AppScript coding.

Comment: You can also use [`SEQUENCE()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244) if all you want is a formula. If you want to go with Apps Script to write the data as plain text then Tanaike's answer is a good option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to insert 100 rows from row 2 of column "B".

In this case, how about the following sample script of Google Apps Script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet.

In this sample, Sheets API is used for inserting the rows into the specific column. So, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services). And, please set your sheet name in the script, and save the script.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.
  const startRow = 2;
  const numRows = 100;
  const insertColumn = 2;

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const requests = [{ insertRange: { range: { sheetId: sheet.getSheetId(), startRowIndex: startRow - 1, endRowIndex: startRow + numRows - 1, startColumnIndex: insertColumn - 1, endColumnIndex: insertColumn }, shiftDimension: "ROWS" } }];
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests }, ss.getId());
  
  sheet.getRange(startRow, insertColumn, numRows).setValues([...Array(numRows)].map((_, i) => [i + 101]));
}
```

- When this script is run, 100 rows are inserted from row 2 of column "B". And, the numbers of 101 to 200 are inserted to the inserted rows.
- If you want to modify the insert column and the number of rows, please modify `startRow`, `numRows`, and `insertColumn`.
- If you want to insert 100 rows from row 2 of all columns, please use the following sample script. In this case, Sheets API is not used.

  ```js
  function myFunction2() {
    const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.
    const startRow = 2;
    const numRows = 100;

    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    sheet.insertRowsBefore(startRow, numRows);

    sheet.getRange(startRow, 2, numRows).setValues([...Array(numRows)].map((_, i) => [i + 101]));
  }
  ```
- As another approach, when only the values from 101 to 200 are inserted from row 2 of column "B", I think that tha following sample script might be able to be used. In this case, Sheets API is not used.

  ```js
  function myFunction3() {
    const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.
    const startRow = 2;
    const numRows = 10;
    const insertColumn = 2;

    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    const range = sheet.getRange(startRow, insertColumn, sheet.getLastRow() - startRow + 1);
    const values = range.getValues();
    values.splice(0, 0, ...[...Array(numRows)].map((_, i) => [i + 101]));
    range.offset(0, 0, values.length, 1).setValues(values);
  }
  ```

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [InsertRangeRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#insertrangerequest)
- [insertRowsBefore(beforePosition, howMany)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertrowsbeforebeforeposition,-howmany)

### Added:

From your following reply,

> I just want to put 1 count from 101 to 200 for lines B2 to B20. I still don't know how to fill in the ... in the command. So the result is an error as shown. i.imgur.com/YcjWyF9.png and i.imgur.com/yC2G71X.png If possible, can you help me write an example in the ".splice(0, 0, ...[...Array(numRows)]" so that I can understand better?

From your question, I couldn't notice that you wanted to simply put the numbers from 101 to 200 using a custom function. From `In google sheet, i want to add new 100 rows from 101 to 200 in column B (Index)`, I thought that you wanted to add new rows and put the numbers to the added new rows.

But, about `I just want to put 1 count from 101 to 200 for lines B2 to B20.`, in this case, do you want to put the values from 101 to 119? Because I think that 200 number values cannot be put into 19 cells.

If my understanding is correct, in this case, how about the following 2 patterns?

#### Pattern 1:

Please put this formula to the cell "B2". This is from Daniel's comment. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75601374/formula-to-add-new-100-rows-from-index-101-to-200#comment133383358_75601374)

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SEQUENCE(100)+100)
```

#### Pattern 2:

If you use a script, please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet and save the script. When you use this script, please put a custom function of `=SAMPLE(101,100)` to a cell "B2". By this, the number values from 101 to 200 are returned to the column.

```
const SAMPLE = (firstNumber, numberOfValues) => [...Array(numberOfValues)].map((_, i) => [i + firstNumber]);
```

Comment: thank you. What means "..." in .setValues([...Array(numRows)]

Comment: @Ho Tro 1 Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your reply, I couldn't understand whether my understanding of your question that could be resolved your issue. I apologize for this. About your additional question of `What means "..." in .setValues([...Array(numRows)]`, in this part, from your question, it is used for putting the numbers from 101 to 200 into the inserted rows.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just want to put 1 count from 101 to 200 for lines B2 to B20. I still don't know how to fill in the ... in the command. So the result is an error as shown. https://i.imgur.com/YcjWyF9.png and https://i.imgur.com/yC2G71X.png  If possible, can you help me write an example in the ".splice(0, 0, ...[...Array(numRows)]" so that I can understand better?

Comment: @Ho Tro 1 Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. From your question, I couldn't notice that you wanted to simply put the numbers from 101 to 200. From `In google sheet, i want to add new 100 rows from 101 to 200 in column B (Index)`, I thought that you wanted to add new rows and put the numbers to the added new rows. From your reply, I updated my answer. Please confirm it.